# How to use shader on Texture?

Tags: xna, hlsl, lighting

I want to build a lighting system based on shaders.http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
For that I need to apply certain functions to textures.
How do I pass a texture through a shader algorithm in C#/XNA?
I tried doing this:

```
foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.Techniques[0].Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();
            }
spriteBatch.Draw(shadowmap,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, range * 2, range * 2),
                new Rectangle((int)screenPos.X - range, (int)screenPos.Y - range, 2 * range, 2 * range),
                Color.White);
```

But it doesn't work.
I also tried this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();

            spriteBatch.Draw(shadowmap,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, range * 2, range * 2),
                new Rectangle((int)screenPos.X - range, (int)screenPos.Y - range, 2 * range, 2 * range),
                Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
            graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
            effect.Parameters["tex"].SetValue(area);
            foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.Techniques[0].Passes)
            {
                pass.Apply();
            }
```

but this also does nothing.
I need to pass the texture through two/three algorithm passes so I need a way to apply a shader to a texture arbitrarily.Is there a way to do this?

Edit:
The HLSL code is this:

```
texture tex;
sampler input  : tex;
float red;
float2 mousepos; 
float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 coords: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float4 color;
    color=tex2D(input,coords.xy);
    color.r=0.9;
    return color;
}



technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    { 
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to have posted the wrong link. Can you edit your post or add it as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an `Effect` to [this overload of `SpriteBatch.Begin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433700.aspx).

You could also use `SpriteSortMode.Immediate` and then `Apply()` different effects before you call `SpriteBatch.Draw`.

(In all other modes, `SpriteBatch` will batch up all its operations - setting effects and drawing - until you call `End`. This gives better performance, but doesn't give you an opportunity to set new effects or states between sprites.)

---

If you are using an effect directly (not through `SpriteBatch`) you can set textures on the graphics device like so:

```
GraphicsDevice.Texture[0] = myTexture;
```

Also `Apply()` your effect, set any other graphics device state, and follow it all by a call to one of the `GraphicsDevice.Draw*()` methods.

---

Note the error in your `foreach` loop, too. You must draw something after each call to `Apply()` (ie: within the loop). You don't need the loop if you pass the effect to `SpriteBatch.Begin`, as `SpriteBatch` will handle it for you internally.

Comment: I have attempted your solution but it still doesn't work.I can't set it it as a texture as it is the rendertarget. What I need to do is to basically take that texture and then transform it.I don't draw it until after running two algorithms on it. I will try using two RenderTargets and pingpong the output from one to the other.

Comment: A `RenderTarget2D` is a `Texture2D`. You can use it as such. The only proviso is that you can't use it as a texture while it is set as a render target. Use `SetRenderTarget(null)` before using it as a texture - it looks like you're already doing this, though? Using multiple targets for a multi-pass effect is the correct solution - as you suggest.